# Is it bad practise to use SquishIt to minify javascript which is already minifed?

Tags: javascript, minify, squishit

In my project I've used quite a few minified scripts to improve performance.

However, amongst these scripts were quite a few un-minified ones too.  Is it ok to use SquishIt to minify and bundle already minified scripts? Is it in any way dangerous for the minifier to process already minified code?

Comment: You should probably run a few tests just to make sure that your minifier does not accidentally increase the size of an already minified script.  Other than that, a minified script is just valid javascript so a good minifier should have no trouble with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minified javascript is still valid javascript, a minifier should have no issues passing minified code through it's parser.