# Are there any known incompatibilities between Javascript minifiers?

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to take a library who compile their distribution scripts with say, Closure Compiler, and compile it with Uglify JS?

Any documented risks?

Comment: I'm just excited to learn there's something called *Uglify JS*

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730910/is-it-bad-practise-to-use-squishit-to-minify-javascript-which-is-already-minifed) for a specific example where it does work.  I'm not sure why you'd want to do that though.  It doesn't really add anything, and some tools, like [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/), will automatically skip already-minified files.

Comment: Closure compiler has [substantial caveats](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) that accompany advanced mode.  Advanced-mode closure is therefore incompatible with virtually all minifiers, i.e., it will mess up most code that other minifiers would handle fine (the exception being code that is writen specifically for advanced-mode closure).

Comment: @MikeChristensen It's actually the one behind jQuery and many others!

Comment: @MosheKatz I know I could just concat the already minified files, just curious if I could use the same uncompiled JS source I want to use in development, and compile it for production along with my own files, rather than keeping every `.js` along with its associated `.min.js`!

Comment: @apsillers Does that mean that the other way is safe, i.e. taking some code designed for Closure Compiler, and compile it with UglifyJS?